# Curve turning into right angle

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, line, perspective

I'm drawing a 3D solar system and have successfully plotted lines for the orbits. However when I am positioned close to the planet the nearest points of the orbit form a right angle making the orbit look very odd. As I move further away, a correct curve forms. Any ideas on what I need to change with respect to my position?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is behaving differently when you are closer to it than farther away, that indicates a code bug. Perhaps you simply think it's a "right angle" but it isn't. More than likely, it's simply a kink, which you notice more up close than farther away. It's still there either way. It's like any linear approximation of a curve: it looks good far away. But up close it looks like what it is: an approximation.

If you want smooth interpolation, you have to use some kind of spline curve. Or, even better, have the planets follow an actual ellipse.

Comment: Thats the problem unfortunately - it is using a catmull roll spline to generate the points between control points that are accurately being plotted by universal constants. Furthermore, the orbit points are not recalculated every frame since time isn't moving.

Comment: @batterj2: I assume you mean "catmull-rom". Those splines can be hard to work with. They can get kinks in them, depending on your choice of value for the "alpha" parameters. The only thing I can suggest is to lower the alpha and see if that helps.